# Meteor, MongoDB saving an associative array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I've got a question about how to create/add to the below schema. Initially bankList starts out as simply an array; the thing is I want to update bankList and add an associative array element:

```
"345899876543456789876544567":{
     type: credit,
     expirationDate: "6/6/15"
}
```

so that the full schema looks like this:

```
bankList:{
    "345899876543456789876544567":{
            type: credit,
            expirationDate: "6/6/15"
    }
}
```

then I can update it to add another element:

```
bankList:{
        "345899876543456789876544567":{
                type: credit,
                expirationDate: "6/6/15"
        },
        "u8y7654e65rt78y564456767997":{
                type: debit,
                expirationDate: "4/5/13"
        }
}
```

My question is how can this be done in one command via MongoDB and using Meteor syntax (Meteor may not yet support something along these lines). Thanks for any help!

Comment: `bankList` looks like a dictionary. Is it an array though?

Comment: I guess it should be a dictionary.

Comment: In PHP they're called associative arrays, and in Python they're called dictionaries, but in JavaScript, they're called objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you would write this:

```js
Collection.update(
  /* selector */, 
  {$set: {"bankList."+key: {type: "credit", expirationDate: "6/6/15"}}}
);
```

However, keys in object literals can only be literals, so you have to do:

```js
var setter = {};
setter["bankList."+key] = {type: "credit", expirationDate: "6/6/15"};
Collection.update(/* selector */, {$set: setter});
```

You could write a function like:

```js
function makeSetter(key, value) {
  var setter = {};
  setter[key] = value;
  return setter;
}

Collection.update(
  /* selector */,
  {$set: makeSetter("bankList."+key, {type: "credit", expirationDate: "6/6/15"})}
);
```